# Problems with pointer to a class

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

I have defined my own class in a Qt project that gives me problems, but I think this could be general C++.

When I try to declare a pointer to my class in any include file in the project myHashMap like

```
myHashMap* map;
```

the compiler gives the error and say "multiple definition of map". What is this? I didn't even define a pointer even, just declared one.

However, putting `myHashMap* map` in a source file doesn't give any errors.

Here is the class definition and declaration, sorry that it looks a bit messy.

```
#include QObject
#include QHash

class myHashMap : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit myHashMap(QObject *parent = 0);

    float Get(const QString& key) const;

    void setValue(const char key, float value)
    {
        // only emit value changed if the value has actually changed

        //if( hash->value(key)  != value)
        //{
              hash->insert(key,value);
              //emit ValueChanged(key, value);
        //}
    }

signals:

public slots:
    //void ValueChanged(const char& key, float newValue);

private:
    QHash<const char, float>* hash;
};

myHashMap::myHashMap(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    hash = new QHash<const char,float>;
}
```

EDIT:

Aaa, bummer, I just forgot to prepend MyHashMap* with the extern keyword. Programming C++ is a nitty-gritty. Wouldn't it make sense if the compiler sent a warning here, like "hello there, you now got multiple definitions in a few headers, forgot an extern keyword?" ?

However, I got a new problem.

In "communication.h" I have declared a namespace like this

```
namespace reference
{
    extern const char potentiometer;
    extern const char KpAngle;
    extern const char KiAngle;
    extern const char KdAngle;

    extern const int        length;

    extern myHashMap* hmap;

    void init();
}
```

In the communication.cpp I want to use *hmap like below, but the compiler returns "undefined reference to hmap". Yet I have included the "communication.h" both in "communication.cpp" and in the *.pro file. See the code below:

```
#include "communication.h"
    namespace reference
    {
    const char potentiometer     = 0x05;
    const char KpAngle           = 0x06;
    const char KiAngle           = 0x07;
    const char KdAngle           = 0x08;

    const int length            =1;

    //QList<const char>* summary = new QList<const char>();

    void init()
    {
            //using namespace reference;
            //#include "communication.h"
        //myHashMap* hmap = new myHashMap();  
        //when using this a hmap is created, however setValue returns undefined  ref            
        //Both methods below returns "undefine reference to hmap". Same if i try "using namespace"
            //reference::hmap = new myHashMap();
            //hmap = new myHashMap();


            /*
            reference::hmap->setValue(potentiometer,-1);
            reference::hmap->setValue(KpAngle,-1);
            reference::hmap->setValue(KiAngle,-1);
            reference::hmap->setValue(KdAngle,-1);*/
    }


}
```

EDIT: Above a pointer to hmap is only declared, not defined. I therefore had do define hmap by putting

myHashMap* hmap directly in the reference scope in "communication.cpp". Now it works.

Comment: Try re-naming map to something else like myMap.

Comment: Your very first line is invalid C++; post your real code. What other definitions of `map` does the compiler mention?

Comment: Comment to your second problem: Have you included the header file for myHashMap in comunications.h?

Answer (score 0):

Prefix the declaration with `extern` in your header file; i.e.:

```
extern myHashMap* map;
```

You will also need to put the variable definition (without `extern`) into a source file somewhere.

The reason this causes a problem is because header files are typically included by multiple source files. Each source file is compiled in its own translation unit, independently of all the other ones. If you put a variable declaration in a header file, then you'll get multiple translation units all trying to define the same variable, causing a conflict.

What you want is for the variable to exist only within a single translation unit, hence the declaration in one source file. The `extern` version just indicates that there is (or will be) a variable with that name and type, but it doesn't actually cause it to be created. It effectively just makes it visible to anything which sees it.

Comment: That answer is straight on. C++ is a nitty-gritty, isn't it? 
However the neatness of Qt compensates for that a bit. Is there a Qt like program featuring for instance Java or Python instead?

Comment: A lot of the quirks of C++ are there for legacy reasons, or because there are still occasional uses for them. I don't tend to use Java or Python, so I'm afraid I don't know about a Qt equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

It is likely that the name "map" is already reserved by another variable or function in a library you are using.Also if you include the header in other headers that are all included in your main file you can get this error.

Comment: I tried to rename "map" without result. The header "myhashmap.h" is not included in other headers the way you describe.